# Difference between two date column if and only values are present in both the columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have two date column 
PRIMARY       CHILD         diff
05-19-1945   01-13-1994     some value in years
03-01-1963
05-33-1933   03-01-1955    some value in years
05-19-1944   06-11-1967    some value in years
             04-22-2020

I want to show difference in years if and only if value is present in both the column 
(driver_data_new['ASGN_BRTH_DT_PRIMARY']-driver_data_new['ASGN_BRTH_DT_CHILD'])/np.timedelta64(1,'Y')
getting the following error
---> 36     driver_data_new['ASGN_BRTH_DT_PRIMARY'].dt.date
     37     driver_data_new['ASGN_BRTH_DT_CHILD'].dt.date
     38     driver_data_new['N_range']=(driver_data_new['ASGN_BRTH_DT_PRIMARY']-driver_data_new['ASGN_BRTH_DT_CHILD'])/np.timedelta64(1,'Y')

AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error `AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values` has nothing to do with only subtracting dates where both values are available. Rather, it has to do with the data types in the columns you're using. At least one of them is not a "datetimelike" object – therefore, the `.dt` accessor just isn't available. Use `df.dtypes` to see which columns are not datetime, and `pandas.to_datetime` to convert. Once you've done that, you'll see how the difference you're trying to calculate is already handled:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a_dt': pd.to_datetime([np.nan, '2019-01-01', '2020-02-04']), 'b_dt': pd.to_datetime([np.nan, np.nan, '2020-03-17'])})
>>> df
        a_dt       b_dt
0        NaT        NaT
1 2019-01-01        NaT
2 2020-02-04 2020-03-17
# Both are datetime types
>>> df.dtypes
a_dt    datetime64[ns]
b_dt    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
>>> df['b_dt'] - df['a_dt']
0       NaT
1       NaT
2   42 days
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```